# How do I avoid the SnapStartNotReadyException error on the first request after 14 days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

We've activated SnapStart for our Lambda function, but we've observed that after 14 days, the first request always fails with `SnapStartNotReadyException` and the user needs to retry again.

The docs have [explained](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart-activate.html#snapstart-function-states) this:

> Inactive – The function version hasn't been invoked for 14 days. When
> the function version becomes Inactive, Lambda deletes the snapshot. If
> you invoke the function version after 14 days, Lambda returns a
> SnapStartNotReadyException response and begins initializing a new
> snapshot. Wait until the function version reaches the Active state,
> and then invoke it again.

How can we make sure the first request will not fail, perhaps by invoking the function periodically?

Comment: You're saying that a function that hasn't been invoked for 14 days might suddenly "get heavy traffic"? That sounds unlikely. If you know that traffic is going to occur (eg when there is an advertising campaign that suddenly attracts traffic), you could invoke the Lambda function beforehand, which would refresh the cache.

Comment: Thanks for reply @JohnRotenstein, it was just example , you assumed it right due something traffic hike.
But point here is we need manual intervention here we need to invoke that lambda periodically to make sure first request will not fail.

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein mentions, if there is traffic, you won't see this issue. I assume your intention was on asking how to be prepared in case an inactive Lambda suddenly may need to respond to high traffic (could be a separate topic altogether).

Answer (score 2):

> after 14 days, the first request always fails with `SnapStartNotReadyException`

Correct - it goes into the [`Inactive`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/functions-states.html) function state.

This happens regardless of SnapStart.

It can also happen for Lambdas with external resources e.g. a Lambda function within a VPC, that would be attached to a Hyperplane ENI. As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-managing-eni), after a 'few weeks' of no usage (14 days), the Lambda will become inactive and the first invocation thereafter will fail.

---

If you want to *avoid* `SnapStartNotReadyException`, invoke the function at least once before 14 days (e.g. once a week or every 13 days) to keep the snapshot and prevent AWS. You can use [EventBridge rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) with an official [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html) available for triggering a Lambda function. The cron expression for every 13 days would be `0 0 */13 * ? *`.

Invoking the Lambda would set it to [`Active`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html#API_CreateFunction_ResponseSyntax) again:

> When the state is `Inactive`, you can reactivate the function by invoking it.

---

If you want to *handle* `SnapStartNotReadyException`, use the SDK-level `FunctionActiveV2` waiter to wait for the Lambda to be ready. Most (if not, all) of the SDKs have this e.g. [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#waiters) or [AWS SDK for Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#Lambda.WaitUntilFunctionActiveV2).

Keeping the Lambda function always in a ready state will prevent any of the requests failing.